How to add a proxy CA certificate to MATLAB
I'm trying to install MATLAB 2024a on a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system.  The system is behind a proxy which requires configuring a proxy and adding a CA Certificate.
For whatever reason, MATLAB does not seem to use the system's certificate store.  There is a place where I can configure a proxy but I cannot find anywhere where I can add/configure a certificate.  Therefore, when I click "test connection", it will fail.  When I try anything that accesses the internet (documentation, install addon, etc), I get a certificate error.
I contacted support and they tell me they don't support that or any SSL interception.  They tell me to use offline installers and manually goto mathworks for documentation.  I find this hard to believe that all the corporations around the world that have proxies that require a certificate are doing this with MATLAB.  Also, on the windows computers (behind the same proxy), it works fine.
Googling, I found an old solution of using keytool to add to the java keystore but that doesnt seem to work anymore.
Does anyone know of a way to resolve this?  For example, firefox does its own thing but has a plugin to make it work.
